# Treeview not finding parent node when adding child node

Tags: vb.net, treeview, nodes

So I have this Treeview to which I manually add some items.
Parent nodes can be added without problems, but when I want to add a child node to a parent node that I search by key, it fails for some reason.

This is the code:

```
tvConstantGroups.Nodes.Add("Boekhouding")
tvConstantGroups.Nodes("Boekhouding").Nodes.Add("Exact") 'These 2 lines fail
tvConstantGroups.Nodes("Boekhouding").Nodes.Add("BoB")
```

The error message that I am getting is that the node "Boekhouding" does not exist (**NULL** / **Nothing**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tvConstantGroups.Nodes.Add("Boekhouding", "Boekhouding")
tvConstantGroups.Nodes("Boekhouding").Nodes.Add("Exact", "Exact")
tvConstantGroups.Nodes("Boekhouding").Nodes.Add("BoB", "Exact")
```

The first parameter of Nodes.Add is Text Not the Name of Node